# Crashing when switching on vibrate, silent and normal

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app crashing when I try to toggle phone modes. For example when I'm in ring mode end I try to switch on silent is crashing, but when I try to toggle vibrate is working fine. Exactly the same thing is happening when I try to change from vibrate to ring. Check status is working fine, there is not crash.

Here is the logcat line:

```
at com.example.lab3_1.MainActivity.onSilent(MainActivity.java:56)
```

That involved the code line:

```
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Here is the main:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AudioManager myAudioManager;
NotificationManager notificationManager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
    getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted())
    {
        Intent intent = new 
 Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
public void onMode(View v)
{
    int mod=myAudioManager.getRingerMode();

    if(mod==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Now in Vibrate Mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else if(mod==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Now in Ringing Mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else if(mod==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Now in Silent Mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public void onRing(View v)
{
    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Now in Ringing Mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onSilent(View v)
{
    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Now in silent Mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onVibrate(View v)
{
    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Now in Vibrate Mode",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

[image: logcat]
[image: error line]

Here is the xml file:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:text="CURRENT MODE CHECK"
    android:onClick="onMode"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt2"
    android:text="RINGER MODE"
    android:onClick="onRing"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt3"
    android:text="SILENT MODE"
    android:onClick="onSilent"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt4"
    android:text="VIBRATE MODE"
    android:onClick="onVibrate"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is a permission issue, check the Android Manifest file and add the appropriate permissions there.

Comment: I keep looking for this particular permission for silent mode, but I can't find. Can you help me with that? If you know the command.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

Comment: I already tried this, don't work.